# C++ struct error

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct Node{
    int ID, power, parent;
    vector<int> connectedNodes;

    Node(int ID_arg, int power_arg){
        ID = ID_arg;
        power = power_arg;
        parent = -1;
    }
};

struct Graph{
    int rootID;
    map<int, Node> nodes;
    map<int,int> subtreeSizes;

    Graph(){
        rootID = 1;
        nodes[1] = new Node(1,0);
    }

};
```

I must be having a serious lapse right now because I have no idea what's wrong. It isn't liking the way I am putting the node in the node map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have a type mismatch, which, if you posted the compile error, would be obvious:

```
nodes[1] = new Node(1,0);
^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Node&       Node*
```

You probably want to do something like:

```
nodes[1] = Node(1, 0);
```

That won't work in this particular case since `Node` isn't default-constructible and [`map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) requires this. The following alternatives will work regardless:

```
nodes.insert(std::make_pair(1, Node(1, 0));
nodes.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::forward_as_tuple(1),
              std::forward_as_tuple(1, 0));
// etc.
```

Comment: Your code is trying to store a newly allocated pointer to a Node in a map of Nodes (not pointers to nodes). Barry's suggestion fixes your problem. If that's not your problem, be more explicit in your question. No mind readers here.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something then because that looks like it is needlessly complex for what I am trying to do.

Comment: I believe Barry is just citing 3 possible solutions to get your code to compile

Comment: I had already tried "nodes[1] =  Node(1,0);" and that gave me an error as well (which is why I tried "new")

Comment: "candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided, Node::Node(const Node&)" for the "struct Node{" line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87540/discussion-between-cppguy-and-doublebass).

Comment: How about `nodes.emplace(1, Node{1,0});`